# What is "knotting solution" called in the US?

Tags: primer, sealer, wood-knots

Having installed some new wood trim in my house, I'd like to seal the knots before painting, so the natural resin doesn't start to show through after a few weeks.

I'm a transplanted Brit living in the US, so I tried searching for "knotting solution" as it is known back in the motherland. However, this just brings up all the UK supplier websites. I'd prefer not to spend $30 shipping on a product that itself is priced less than that. I can't seem to figure out what the same product is called on this side of the Atlantic though. Any ideas?

Some paints/primers claim to be up to the task, but I have tried in the past with Kilz on other similar projects and found that it only delays the resin, doesn't stop it completely. Would really prefer to find a product dedicated to solving this specific, commonly encountered issue.

Comment: We really need a page of UK/US translations. Things like this crop up a lot ;)

Comment: What species of wood are you using? What kind and colour of paint are you intending to use? Where in the US is this?

Comment: Once again, two peoples separated by a common language, eh, @Tetsujin? :D

Comment: Jim - some kind of pine, looking to get a glossy white finish, in Ohio. Would prefer not to stink up the house with oil-based paint, but I don't mind treating just the knots with something oil-based.

Comment: @Tetsujin worth a tag?

Comment: @nitsua60 - one might be nice, but often these things crop up in comments, rather than as direct questions,  as people are trying to figure out what a left-handed grippling flange is where *you* live, or translating the many types of cement-based product that can be spread on a wall. Cooking have such a page for food-related translations. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/42066 It breaks all the 'rules' as a huge amount of the info is in the question, but it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a knot blocking wood primer.  Supposedly a few coats of shellac-based stain blocker, e.g. Zinsser BIN, will do the trick.

Comment: In support for this, I found a document on Rustin's (a UK wood finish producer) and they say their knotting solution is "pure shellac and alcohol"

Comment: Yup. Shellac or "shellac based primer" will both work.

Comment: You're not blocking the *knot*, you're blocking the tannins in the knot from leeching.

Comment: I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @matt. I'm only using the terminology from manufacturers of such products.